# asp.net master pages, content pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

i have a master page with three sections, left pane + 2 right panes (one top header and one main screen area)

i want to have the main screen area dynamically fill a url based on a link click from the top header pane.

so in the header if i have three links - assume i have three pages (one.aspx, two.aspx, three.aspx) and i want to click a one, two, three link in the header pane of the master and have the content load in the main area of each associated child page in the main areas.

any idea?

Comment: Smells like a frame-based solution, but realistically you could use AJAX to do things like this.

Comment: Are you thinking in old fashioned frames? Think of MasterPages as includes. So you can link directly to your pages, not to a page in a frame.

Comment: Are you talking about some sort of AJAX construct? The behavior you're describing sounds like simple master page behavior where each of one/two/three.aspx incorporates your master page and has a Content control that directs to your main content area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of ASP .NET master pages are to do exactly what you are wanting without needing to fill areas of the page.

What I would suggest doing is moving the content that does not change per page (e.g. left pane and the top header/right pane) into the master page. and create a contentplaceholder for your main screen.

Then create your one.aspx, two.aspx, three.aspx pages and have them use your new master page.  Now, when you edit the pages, the only area you will edit will be the content for the main screen area.

Any changes you make on the master page will be immediately reflected on all three pages without having to update each one.

If you had a different goal in mind please let me know.  I'll do what I can to help.

Answer (score 2):

When you created your pages you should have selected the MasterPage.
On each page you fill the content areas of your MasterPage.

So if you want to link to your pages you can put the links in each page's Head ContentPlaceHolder. So you link to 'one.aspx', 'two.aspx' and 'three.aspx' directly.

Each page will load it's MasterPage contents when it's requested. So it works like includes not frames (forget frames).

Answer (score 1):

Just create your master page with your layout divs and use the  to leave a place holder inside your content tab.

Next create a new page that uses your master page as its base and inside the automatically generated  tag put your specific content for that page.

Create a new page inheriting the master page for each content page you want the header links to point to.

Hey presto no need for frames or script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely follow your intent, but if I do get it, it sounds to me like what you want is a floating frame.